# CSP implementation on Velocity templates

Tags: java, velocity, content-security-policy

I am trying to implement CSP header for my website. But I am facing weird issue.
sometimes the content of css and javascript get merged in js file . For e.g. the content of css file is getting included in js file before the actual content of javascript starts with css content with jetty header.

```
Notes {    color: grey;
font-size: 14px;
}

.width-100{
width : 100px;
}

.report-table-margin{
margin-left: 75px;
}

.settings-message{
width: 800px; 
color: grey;
font-size: 12px;
}


.category_width_15{ 
width:30px; 
}
.category_width_30{
width:30px; 
}
.category_width_45{
width:45px; 
}
.category_width_60{
width:60px;
}
.category_width_75{
width:75px; 
}
.category_width_90{ 
width:90px; 
}
.category_width_105{
width:105px;
}
.category_width_120{ 
width:120px; 
}
.category_width_145{
width:145px;
}
.category_width_150{
width:150px; 
}
.category_width_165{
width:165px; 
}
.category_width_180{
width:180px; 
}
.category_width_195{
width:195px; 
}
.category_width_210{
width:210px; 
} 
.category_width_225{
width:2HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Content-Type: application/javascript
Last-Modified: Mon, 11 Jul 2016 15:17:26 GMT
ETag: F4m9JEra3NUTACcLX_1WT1WuRN0
Content-Length: 269
Server: Jetty(9.1.3.v20140225)


jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
jQuery('#ssl3TestDiv').css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: The question isn't very clear, can you clarify?